RPC framework with Web JS Server, C# Client, and single-request stream-response support
I am controlling a webpage via Google Chrome from a C# plugin loaded by a separate program. I cannot change that the plugin must be written in C#, and I must control a web page via Chrome from it. This means I have a minimum of four nodes in communication:

the C# plugin, which via any IPC-capable transport method talks to
the Native Messaging application spawned by Chrome, which via stdin/stdout talks to
the Chrome Extension service worker, which via chrome.scripting talks to
the web page

2↔3 and 3↔4 are effectively required to communicate via JSON objects, due to how Chrome Extensions work.
Right now I'm hand-rolling an RPC protocol, but it has a lot of issues:

I have to duplicate object definitions between the TypeScript and C# side, and there's no way for me to get automatic JSON Codecs for those objects
It's very hard to keep track of the protocol in two places: I've twice already ran into an error due to forgetting to handle a case on the TypeScript side
If I want cancellation or error handling, I have to reimplement that entirely myself, instead of relying on a framework that can already do it. This wouldn't be a big issue, except I do need to handle unsubscribing from streams, which as far as I can tell is essentially cancellation.

I have looked into a few options:

gRPC has streaming responses and cancellation, but it can't work in this case due to the requirement of HTTP/2 transport; there's no way to implement a "server"/handler on the web JS side
As of 2024-07-11, Apache Dubbo doesn't have up-to-date C# support, and the guide links for web JS are broken. The documentation images heavily imply that web JS is client-only, and I can't implement an RPC server there
Apache Thrift seems to be the closest in terms of platform/transport support, but it does not support streaming/"post-request"-unprompted responses, which I would like to use to be able to receive continual updates from the webpage

By far the most frustrating issue I have had is that searching for "RPC Server on Web JS" is impossible, because every result is about making Web Servers on NodeJS that happen to serve RPC protocols.
So, are there any RPC frameworks that:

support generating a client in C# and a server in web-compatible JS from a shared protocol definition
easily support custom transports (specifically Chrome Extension ports) and optionally JSON as a serialization mechanism
support subscribing to streaming responses?

